# Example for Halide generated mex usage in windows matlab

Tags: halide

**Summary:**

When trying to run halide-mex from Matlab with an example similar to `iir_blur.cpp` and `apps\HelloMatlab\run_blur.m` in windows - the Matlab application crashes on calling mex.

The halide generator under evalution has two parameters one float value and another as float image. The function is to add the float value (constant) to the image array and return the result.

1. The `mex_halide` utility does not work for Microsoft Visual studio compiler.
   I have launched Matlab from Visual Studio compiler tools shell with environment variable set for `HALIDE_CXX` to `cl.exe`

   The compiler options in the `mex_halide.m` utility seems to be for non Visual Studio compiler.

   - Do we have a similar script for Matlab-Halide from windows ?
2. Here are some things I have tried.

   Modified the `mex_halide.m` script and was able to get it generate `.mexw64` file using Visual-Studio-2013.

   - When I call the mex function, matlab crashes with no information to debug! What could be the reason for crash. What am I missing ? 
     I am invoking the mex like `computeSum(constantVal, input, output)` I have allocated the input and output with `zeros(5,5,'single')` and `constantVal = single(5)`.

I am running Matlab 2015b

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that it crashes? that can be a segfault, and have nothing to do with halide

Comment: Could you provide pointers to existing `halide-matlab-mex` example for windows platform ?